# Text to the side of center aligned text

Tags: horizontal-alignment

My apologies if this has been asked before. I wasn't able to find it.

I'm trying to write text to the side of center aligned text. Something like the following.

```
|                         TEXT (continuation)              |
```

Where the TEXT is centralized and the (continuation) is immediately to the right of the TEXT.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify whether "(subtitle)" should appear (a) to the immediate right of "TITLE" or (b) to the far right, snugged up against the right-hand margin.

Comment: To the immediate right. That's what I meant by "left aligned to the right side" but now I see that wasn't very clear.

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. Please provide an example, what you like to have and where you stuck in your effort.

Comment: The example I provided is the best I can come up with, unfortunately. My problem is exactly that I don't know how to produce anything close to the result I'm looking for, or where to look for that information

Comment: Please, add some information about the context this would appear in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{\ TITLE \rlap{(subtitle)}}
\author{John Doe}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. The OP may actually be looking for `\title{\hfill TITLE \hfill\llap{(subtitle)}}`. However, I may have misinterpreted the OP's objective.

Comment: @Mico,Thank you very much!  I try to reproduce showed image, where the subtitle is immediately after the title.

Comment: Thanks for the response! In this example however the TITLE is ever so slightly left of center. Also, I know I wrote TITLE in my question but is there an approach that does not depend of \maketitle?

Comment: @WilliamA.Noble, I slightly correct answer. Showed idea (use of `rlap` command) can be used at any case, not just title. Actually, your question is not very clear, so please edit it and show (in form of MWE) what you try so far.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @WilliamA.Noble, glad to hear this. Well, if answer fulfill your expectations, you my consider to accept it (by clicking on the check mark at the top left side of answer) and by this inform audience of site, that your problem is solved :-)

Comment: To fully center the string "Title", just change `\title{\ TITLE \rlap{(subtitle)}}` to `\title{TITLE\rlap{ (subtitle)}}`. Note the space at the start of the argument of `\rlap`.

Comment: @Zarko I forgot I could do that. I'm still relatively new to SE